# RadRails and Gemfile, am I missing something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, rubygems, radrails

Is there a way to have my Ruby on Rails project reference the Gems that are declared in Gemfile?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadRails 2.x was released before Bundler and Gemfiles existed and it is now deprecated. Studio 3 contains Ruby/Rails functionality and should index any gems installed into whatever ruby is on your PATH (it respects RVM too), and then use that for content assist.